# Spartacus Storefront custom theme examples? Changing colors and bootstrap variables?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-ui-bootstrap, spartacus-storefront

There does not seem to be clear examples of custom storefronts or custom styling/themes for Spartacus.

I would like to understand how I implement a custom theme where we have different colours and theme defaults. I cannot find any examples on how to do this correctly with Spartacus. Am I missing anything?

Any feedback would be really appreciated.

An example of what I would have expected would work:

src/styles.scss

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

$styleVersion: 3.2;

// change theme-colors here
$primary: #000;
$secondary: #000;
$success: #5dac06;
$danger: #db0002;
$warning: #ffc107;
$info: #17a2b8;
$light: #d3d6db;
$dark: #000;
$background: #f4f4f4;
$inverse: #ffffff;
$text: #212738;

@import '~@spartacus/styles/index';
```

The bootstrap defaults are not overwritten. Can anyone simply share an example of how I should be doing this with Spartacus specifically.

Comment: You can check this for an example of a custom theme implemented in Spartacus. It imports the default spartacus styles in the root `styles.scss` and proceeds to overwrite them in the `styles` directory: 
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/spartacus-capybara/tree/develop/src

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I tried the new 3.2 version and found out that the "old" way of overwriting the theme variables doesn't work anymore. But I too couldn't find any documentation on why it doesn't work anymore and how it should be done now. The only thing that I could find out was that I could overwrite the CSS custom properties. But only if I set it to important. It works but that can't be the right way. Does anybody has further information?

```
$styleVersion: 3.2;

:root {
  --cx-color-primary: dodgerblue !important;
}

@import '~@spartacus/styles/index';
```

Comment: This is currently the approach I have been using too. Which is a bit frustrating. Overwriting CSS seems redundant when using Sass in the first place. I noticed that Spartacus actually overrides some core css for bootstrap which currently is not something that can be disabled.

Comment: For reference, I below the following section is where the overrides happen:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus-styles-builds/blob/a8774b2248b90cedc90fae2deb84c4b2f7d0ceb7/scss/app.scss#L19

Comment: Ok so I found out how to do it. I posted an answer to this question. It has to do with the $theme-colors variable. I added it with the updated colours and its now working as expected.

Comment: Hi @AdrianHolmes, I tried your answer but it is still not working for me. I copied the code in your answer but the styles still get overwritten be the Spartacus styles. Have you changed anything else besides adding the $theme-colors?

Comment: Turns out that it does overwrite the variables initially, but there seems to be double CSS overwriting it. It seems in the development environment the CSS is duplicated. I need to investigate this a bit more...

Comment: hi @AdrianHolmes did you find any solution?

Comment: So it turns out there was a duplicate loading in the spartacus library itself. It looks like it has since been updated, but if you are using an older version of spartacus then you would probably find the following fix is not there:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/commit/502b7c47fb9aa963fc39dc122dc54a2dcafbc0fa

Comment: My work around was to create a custom cart/_index.scss and try match how it is but exclude the import for the entire spartacus library.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this if someone else might need this info. Turns out that I was close, I just need to added an extra piece:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

$styleVersion: 3.2;


// change theme-colors here
$primary: #38a8ae !default;
$secondary: #148181 !default;
$success: #5dac06 !default;
$danger: #e51f34 !default;
$warning: #ffc107 !default;
$info: #17a2b8 !default;
$light: #d3d6db !default;
$dark: #161C23 !default;
$background: #f4f4f4 !default;
$inverse: #ffffff !default;
$text: #000000 !default;
$transparent: transparent !default;
$visual-focus: #6d9df7 !default;
$background-focus: rgba(80, 176, 244, 0.1);

$theme-colors: (
  'primary': $primary,
  'secondary': $secondary,
  'success': $success,
  'danger': $danger,
  'warning': $warning,
  'info': $info,
  'light': $light,
  'dark': $dark,
  'background': $background,
  'inverse': $inverse,
  'text': $text,
  'transparent': $transparent,
  'visual-focus': $visual-focus,
  'background-focus': $background-focus,
);


@import '~@spartacus/styles/index';
```

I needed to add the $theme-colors variable with the updated colours. Now the CSS is compiled correctly and no need to override the css.